# In stable-Baselines3 PPO what is nsteps?

Tags: python-3.x, stable-baselines

In the SB3 PPO algorithm, what does the n_steps refer to?  Is this the number of steps to run the environment?  If so, what if the environment terminates prior to reaching n_steps?

and how does it relate to batch_size?

I am running 12 environments using SubProcVecEnv, but not sure how n_steps and batch_size impact the model while training.

Answer (score 2):

there is a simple formula, which is always true for on-policy algos in sb:

```
n_updates = total_timesteps // (n_steps * n_envs)
```

from that it follows that `n_steps` is the number of experiences which is collected from a single environment under the current policy before its next update. My subjective basic practice is to set this value to be equal to the episode length, especially if there is a terminal reward.

Then, there is slight terms misusage in sb3. Actually, a **batch** for PPO is the same as **the size of rollout buffer**, which is equal to `n_steps * n_envs`. What is however meant by `batch_size` is in turn the **minibatch** size, where your take some subset of your buffer (batch) with random shuffling.  Lots of people set `batch_size = n_steps`, so that your networks consume the whole batch, which may be the case when you have enough video memory and exploit population-based training. However, a standard practice is to use the smaller sized minibatches so that `n_steps` is divisible by it, like in default parameters for PPO in sb3.